# android java awaitable file downloader function

Tags: java, android, function, async-await

I'm new in android, I found nothing for awaitable function to download files. For example in c#:

```
bool result;
result = await DownloadMyFileAsync(url, file);
MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
```

How can I do it in android java?

Comment: You have to writing your own download service, using system one or downloading asynchronously within the activity depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply await an async task to finish on android application.
The system prevent network calls on main thread.
You must implement an AsyncTask (see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) passing an interface representing a download listener.
Doing this allow you to invoke a function on UI class such as your activity on async task post executed.
The download stuff must then be included on this async task.

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
 protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     int count = urls.length;
     long totalSize = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
         publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
         // Escape early if cancel() is called
         if (isCancelled()) break;
     }
     return totalSize;
 }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
 }
}
```